# 10.8 reminders snooze duration

Tags: macos, calendar

When I get either a Calendar or Reminders notification, I have the option to 'snooze':

[image: reminder alert with snooze]

I would like to be able to say something like 'remind me in 10 minutes' or 'remind me in 2 hours' (much like the iCal notifcations used to allow in <= 10.7).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Apple failed to include a multi-time snooze feature in the Mountain Lion version of Calendar.  LIke you, thousands of us would like to have this feature back.

Go to [www.apple.com/feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback) and tell them.  I did.  If enough people point out this omission, they will address it sooner than later.

Power in numbers!

Answer (score 7):

In Mountain Lion, you can select the snooze duration by holding down the button:

[image: Snooze menu]

The various times in the menu differ based on the length of time before the event begins.  There's no visual clue that this functionality is available, but it is.

**Update:** The same functionality is available in Yosemite

[image: Snooze menu 2]

Comment: Bring My Cake deserves HUGE accolades for pointing out holding down the snooze button gets one optional amounts of time! Alas, though, in my version of Mountain Lion, that trick does NOT work! Perhaps he or she meant Mavericks? Now, is there a way to send away a bunch of alerts all at once? And, to bring back an alert that you just inadvertently sent away by clicking "close"?! And, you have no idea which of several it was?

Comment: I think I was using Mountain Lion, but I have since upgraded to Yosemite so I am not sure.  I will try to check.  In reference to you other questions, in Yosemite you can dismiss all alerts that originate from a single app in the Notification menu, though I'm not sure that's exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

[SnoozeMaster](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snoozemaster/id614955483?mt=12) solved this issue for me. It works with both Calendar and Reminders alerts, giving you many more options than the default OS X Mountain Lion 15-minute Snooze. I didn't want to switch to a non-Apple program (such as BusyCal) because I like the way Apple Calendar syncs easily with my other OS X and iOS devices. SnoozeMaster allows me to keep using Apple Calendar, but with a much more flexible Snooze option.

You can enter any value you like for the Snooze period. Alternately, you can configure your own drop down menu (similar to the default Apple drop down in OS X Lion). This configurable menu can contain as many items as you like, with time values of your choosing (5 min, 15 min, 3 hrs, 7 days, 0.5 min, etc.).

While running, [SnoozeMaster](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snoozemaster/id614955483?mt=12) lives in the menu bar under a ".zZ" icon. To insure that it's always monitoring your alerts, I recommend setting SnoozeMaster's preferences to:

```
Start at Login: On
```

I also recommend turning off Apple Notifications for Calendar and Reminders. These settings can be found in System Preferences:

```
System Preferences > Notifications > Calendar > Calendar Alert Style: None
System Preferences > Notifications > Reminders > Reminders Alert Style: None
```

Then you will only get alerts generated by SnoozeMaster and not Apple Notifications.

Comment: Note that Snoozemaster costs $1.99.

Comment: "This app is not currently available in your country or region." As of today's date, in my region (United States).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that drove us crazy too, so we wrote a menubar app to have control over snoozing the Apple Calendar alerts.  Check out "SnoozeMaster" on the App Store.  Hope everyone likes it?

Comment: "This app is not currently available in your country or region." As of today's date, in my region (United States).

Answer (score 1):

[Busycal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/index.html) seems to be the main contender for the throne and it has a 30 day trial. I am about a week into my trial and I was fairly sure I was going to buy it within the next day or two as it is at a reduced price til the end of the month... until I went and looked at [SnoozeMaster](http://appshopper.com/mac/utilities/snoozemaster) (which is only $2) and which seems to do the job - so I'm off to buy that instead.

update: Bought it and it seems perfect - much better than the old Apple iCal one in Lion as you can set any times you want - and certainly better than Mountain Lion as that is totally unusable! Just sent them an email request asking if they would add an option to put off alarms until 9am tomorrow - that would be perfect.

Comment: i've since moved to busycal and it's been great.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this answer in the Apple Discussion Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4142568?start=0&tstart=0), it appears to be no.